# Select the maximum value after eliminating a selected value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large data set (300 millions rows) and I need an efficient (or fast) algorithm that will do the job. So here are few rows of dataset.

```
db = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,3,4,5], 'T': [1,2,6,7], 'G': [8, 1, 4, 6], 
                 'C': [1,1 , 3, 4], 'basecall' : ['G', 'A', 'G', 'T']})
```

I need a new column  (`max_eliminate`) and it is calculated by eliminating the corresponding value in the `basecall` column and then find the maximum for the rest of the three values. So for row one, the `basecall` is "G" and after eliminating the corresponding value, which is 8 and the three remaining values are 2, 1, 1. The `max_eliminate` column will select the max of these values, which is 2 for this row.

```
db_new = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,3,4,5], 'T': [1,2,6,7], 'G': [8, 1, 4, 6], 
                       'C': [1,1 , 3, 4], 'basecall' : ['G', 'A', 'G', 'T'], 
                       'max_eliminate' : [2, 2, 6, 6]})
```

I will read this dataset by chunk of 1 million rows at a time

Comment: What happens when another column has same value as `basecall` example: if column `A` for first row is `8` , what shall the output return?

Comment: @anky the output should be 8 since after eliminating the 8, which is corresponding to G. The max of the rest of three is 8, which is corresponding to A.

Comment: @kelvinfrog If duplicate values need to be consider then you can go with @ALollz `numpy` based answer.

Comment: After I think about it more, I need to use @ALollz numpy approach to solve the program. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stack` then filter out the rows where the `'basecall'` is the same as the original column header. Then `agg` with `max` over the original index.

```
s = db.set_index('basecall', append=True).stack()
db['max_eliminate'] = (s[s.index.get_level_values('basecall') != s.index.get_level_values(-1)]
                          .groupby(level=0).max())

   A  T  G  C basecall  max_eliminate
0  2  1  8  1        G              2
1  3  2  1  1        A              2
2  4  6  4  3        G              6
3  5  7  6  4        T              6
```

---

Another `numpy` approach is to use broadcasting to create the mask for the DataFrame columns (other than `'basecall'`), then `max` along the rows as it ignores `NaN`

```
m = db.columns[:-1].to_numpy() == db['basecall'].to_numpy()[:, None]
#[[False False  True False]
# [ True False False False]
# [False False  True False]
# [False  True False False]]

db['max_eliminate'] = db.drop(columns='basecall').mask(m).max(1)
```

Comment: Liked the broadcasting approach :)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) to lookup the values based on columns in `db['basecall']`, then use [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select the columns except `basecall` and use [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to mask the lookup values i.e `s`, finally use [`DataFrame.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) along `axis=1`:

```
s = db.lookup(db.index, db['basecall'])
db['max_eliminate'] = db.filter(regex='^(?!basecall)')\
                        .mask(lambda x: x.eq(s, axis=0)).max(1)
```

Result:

```
   A  T  G  C basecall  max_eliminate
0  2  1  8  1        G            2.0
1  3  2  1  1        A            2.0
2  4  6  4  3        G            6.0
3  5  7  6  4        T            6.0
```